# wkhtmltopdf in C# - for converting large number of html files with file name having spaces

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I would like to convert large number of html files from a directory to PDF using C#.
How to pass input file name and output file name which contains spaces.
Eg wkhtmltopdf.exe 'test file.html' 'test file.pdf'
This is working using command prompt but not working in C#. Please help how to pass file names with spaces in it. The exe is taking spaces in file name as delimiter.

Comment: Hi mhemant, Welcome to stackoverflow, Please share your code snippet what you have tried so far and what error you are facing.

Comment: Would like to know how to pass command line arguments string  with spaces in it to wkhtmltopdf exe

Comment: Use a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve